# How can I use `firstValueFrom` with `WebSocketSubject` without closing the underlying web socket?

Tags: websocket, rxjs

I am using a `WebSocketSubject`, and I often want to block execution until a given event arrives, which is why I use `firstValueFrom`, like in the following code:

```js
let websocket = new WebSocketSubject<any>(url);
let firstMessage = await firstValueFrom(websocket.pipe(filter(m => true));
```

I only have one issue, which is that `firstValueFrom` calls `websocket.unsubscribe()` when it resolves the promise, but on a `WebSocketSubject` that has the effect of closing the underlying Web Socket, which I want to keep open!

Currently, I have thought of a few possible ways out:

- Writing an equivalent of `firstValueFrom` that does not unsubscribe.
  **Counter argument**: I would prefer not reimplementing a function that is nearly perfect, except for one small issue;
- Using another `Subject` that will subscribe to `WebSocketSubject`, and I will use `firstValueFrom` on that subject.
  **Counter argument**: In terms of usage, I see potential confusion to have two `Subject` objects, and having to know which one to use (E.g. Use `websocket.next` for sending messages upstream, and only use `websocketProxy` for receiving messages, and *never* get confused between the two!);
- Using `multiplex` to create temporary `Observable` objects that will then be closed by `firstValueFrom` without issue.
  **Counter argument**: As I am not actually multiplexing in this case, I would rather not use that method, whose signature and usage seems overkill for my use case.

In short, I suspect that I am missing something basic (e.g. an appropriate `OperatorFunction`) that would allow me to make it so that the `unsubscribe` call made by `firstValueFrom` does not result in the underlying web socket being closed.

Comment: The Websocket subject is intended to be lazy and will close connection whenever there are no subscribers.  What is your intention after you receive this first value?

Comment: I want to keep the connection open to send and receive messages, because I have a lot of messages to send and receive after the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you want to always have a subscription so the socket connection stays open. I don't think `firstValueFrom` is the proper tool for the job. I think its simpler to just create an explicit subscription.

If the intent is to keep it open for the lifetime of the app, just subscribe at app launch.

Since you want to filter out the first several emissions until some condition is met, you can use [`skipWhile`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/skipwhile):

```js
const websocket = new WebSocketSubject<any>(url);
const messages = websocket.pipe(skipWhile(m => m !== 'my special event'));

websocket.subscribe(); // keep socket open


// listen
messages.subscribe(m => console.log('message received:', m);

// send
websocket.next('hello server');
```

---

It may be worth creating a light wrapper class around the rxjs websocket that handles keeping the connection open and filtering out the first few events:

```js
class MyWebsocket {
  private websocket = new WebSocketSubject<any>(this.url);
  public messages = websocket.pipe(skipWhile(m => m !== 'my special event'));

  constructor(private url) {
    this.websocket.subscribe(); // keep socket open
  }
 
  public sendMessage(message: any) {
    this.websocket.sendMessage(message);
  }
}
```

```js
const websocket = new MyWebsocket(url);

// listen
websocket.messages.subscribe(m => console.log('message received:', m);

// send
websocket.sendMessage('hello server');
```

Comment: Why would `firstValueFrom` not be the appropriate method for the job? I have a lot of situations where I am waiting for exactly one message from the server, and being able to get it as a `Promise` for ease of use in an `async` method is exactly what I want.

Comment: I meant that it wasn't appropriate to use it to maintain a long term subscription, it's meant to just get a single value and complete (*which I see is what you are talking about in your comment*)

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were saying about "*block execution until a given event arrives*".  I was thinking you didn't want any subscribers of the websocket to receive those emissions until the specific event was received. But after re-reading, maybe that's not the case...

Comment: If that's the case, I think doing exactly what you were doing is fine, but then just create an explicit subscription somewhere early in the code so the connection stays alive.

Comment: All right, yes, of course `firstValueFrom` should not be used to maintain a long-term subscription. And by "block execution", I meant basically "I want method execution to resume only after that - for which the most convenient method is using a `Promise` and `await`".

Comment: Using the information from your reply, I have added a `websocket.subscribe()` line between the two lines in my sample code, and it works fine now. Thank you! (The information I was missing is that the web socket is only kept open as long as there is at least one subscriber)